# Ruby on rails: &ndash; in xml.builder file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

My question seems to be not very complicated. I need in "-" in my xml builder file

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0", :encoding => "windows-1251"             
xml.autos do               
   xml.auto-list do
     @autos.each do |offer|
     xml.offer do
     end
end
end
end
```

but

```
undefined method `list' for #<#<Class:0xb32881c>:0xbc96f84>
```

also, i tried

```
&ndash; &#8211; and &amp;ndash;
```

Comment: It’s 2014, if my calendar doesn’t lie to me. Why not use the unicode symbol (–), feel free to copy-paste it from here. BTW, mdash: —.

Comment: After using (–), i got This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 8: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a method "auto-list" on your "xml" object, but this is not a a valid method name, because of the dash.

Method names can only contain the following: letters, numbers, underscores, "?", "!" and "=".

Comment: but how can i get such record in output xml: <auto-list>

Comment: I assume you wrote the "auto-list" method yourself. Just rename it to "auto_list"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use the "tag!" command, like this:

```
xml.autos do               
  xml.tag! 'auto-list' do
    @autos.each do |offer|
      xml.offer do
      end
    end
  end
end
```